# Can not deploy a wso2 car file

Tags: wso2-esb

I am following the bellow tutorial for creating a wso2 project and i am new in this area . But car file is not  deploying as per tutorial.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Sending+a+Simple+Message

System log shows like this:

[2018-10-15 15:45:22,262]  WARN - ApplicationManager No artifacts found to be deployed in this server. Ignoring Carbon Application :SampleServicesCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car

NB: But I can deploy another car file using UI.

Answer (score 1):

There can be two problems here, your CAR file does not actually contain any artifacts. Or the artifacts in the CAR file have a Server Role that does not match the ESB.

1. Check the pom.xml file in your CAR project using the Composite Application Project pom editor (use right click on the pom.xml file) and see if the various components are selected to be included in the CAR file.
2. Out of the box your ESB only knows the server role EnterpriseServiceBus,  in the pom.xml of the CAR project check what Server Role is selected for the components. If the selected server Role does not match the EnterpriseServiceBus it will not be deployed on your ESB even if included in your CAR file.

If these are both set correctly and it still does not deploy check the contents of the actual CAR you are uploading as Rangas explained.

Answer (score 0):

This WARN can happen when the *car* file does not include any artifacts to deploy into the server. You can do a quick test to check whether the artifacts are included inside the *car* file. Extract the *car* file and check the content inside it. It should include the artifacts(endpoints, APIs etc.) which you created and also inside the *artifacts.xml* it will hold dependencies to your artifacts.

In case if you can't find the artifacts inside the car file, follow the link bellow again and check you have packaged the artifacts properly into the car file.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Packaging+Artifacts+into+Composite+Applications